# Problems with sendExtraCommand and force_xtra_injection

Tags: android, locationmanager

I'm working on an app that actually works fine if the device is rooted, but now I'm doing something for non rooted device. At this point I need to use the following (or something like it) in order to download the xtra.bin and unpack in the device >

```
    public static void downloadGPSXtra(Context context)
{

        LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService("location");
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        locationmanager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_xtra_injection", bundle);
        locationmanager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_time_injection", bundle);

}
```

Then I use the following to "execute" it >

```
        lto_downloader.downloadGPSXtra(lto_downloader.this);
```

Ok, I don't know why (obviously), but it didn't work. In only got some reply from logcat about the time injection >

```
    D/GpsLocationProvider( 3131): NTP server returned: 1297364952086 (Thu Feb 10 19:
09:12 GMT+00:00 2011) reference: 9750010 certainty: 337 system time offset: -483
80
```

I know that the "force_xtra_injection" it's not working due to I don't see any changes at `/data/gps/lto.dat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm the author of GPS Status, and I really do not do anything else than what you are currently doing. (i.e. calling the sendExtraCommand method. In fact that 3 line of code is also in my program :), I guess that those files are implementation/handset specific. I do not even have /data/gps directory at all on my handset. (Nexus One)

Comment: Ok! I will try to have the GPS hardware working while the command is injectec, maybe that is the trick. Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 1):

I guess, your code is working. (assuming you have added the required permissions to your manifest). You should not expect any changes in the app's data directory. The XTRA data downloaded is directly injected into the GPS subsystem and not stored on filesystem at all. I my experience the only way to check if the inject was successful is to reset the GPS state, then call the inject method and see how fast the GPS can acquire the lock.

Answer (score 0):

LocationManager will return false only, and only when the command will be unknown to it. If the command is known to the LocationManager, it queues this command and then returns true, thats all it does.

Whether injection is successful or not, there is no way to check but watching logcat (if anything will show up there).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to determine if the XTRA data download was successful. I have tested this on a Nexus S. The logcat will not show anything, and the RIL log will merely show that a request has been made – but not if it was successful. So unfortunately Android doesn't give us any option but to blindly fire `force_xtra_injection` at the `LocationManager` and hope it's going to be successful.

Edit: I just came across [this paper](https://wiki.csem.flinders.edu.au/pub/CSEMThesisProjects/ProjectKoto0003/koto0003_Master_Thesis.pdf), which on page 34 describes how to change the debug level of the GPS driver stack to get status messages of NTP and AGPS ijection operations. However, this requires a rooted device and might not work with every driver implementation.

Comment: Broken link to paper... Perhaps you've meant to alter `DEBUG_LEVEL` in `/etc/gps.conf`. DEBUG LEVELS: 0 - none, 1 - Error, 2 - Warning, 3 - Info, 4 - Debug, 5 - Verbose. Then `logcat -C | grep --line-buffered LocSvc_eng`.