# Android: How to reset and download A-GPS data?

Tags: android, gps

How can I programmatically reset and download new A-GPS data in an Android application? In other words, how do the "Manage A-GPS state" tools work in the [GPS Status & Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) app?

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to use `LocationManager.sendExtraCommand(String provider, String command, Bundle extras)`. This will allow you to delete all or part of the GPS data, so it will redownload it. The docs are [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#sendExtraCommand%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29), but a quick rundown of the arguments, referenced from [this code](http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/blobs/fd9f42a6967370490cd2c66e628ccbf2eacc4a4b/location/java/com/android/internal/location/GpsLocationProvider.java#line485)(for a GPS Provider):

For `provider`, use `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`.

For `command`, use `"delete_aiding_data"`

For extras, if you pass `null`, it will delete all data. If you want to delete specific data only(such as just the almanac or position), you can use the flags found in [this function](http://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/blobs/fd9f42a6967370490cd2c66e628ccbf2eacc4a4b/location/java/com/android/internal/location/GpsLocationProvider.java#line495) as extras in the bundle.

Don't forget to add `android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS` to your permission list in the manifest!

Comment: Thank you very much - this is extremely helpful. Is there any other command that can speed up the process of re-downloading the data after it is deleted? Also, do you have experience with whether it is better to delete only specific data or all of it when the GPS seems to be stuck?

Comment: I haven't used the GPS features of Android much, so I can't say for sure. I can say that on aircraft GPS systems, the entire data is dumped when we do a reset. Traditionally, it can take up to several minutes to reacquire it, depending on what algorithm is used to do initial satellite-finding.

Comment: How do you decide when to do a reset on an aircraft? Is it something that is done just on a routine basis when the plane is on the ground, or is it possible to detect when a reset will be useful based on the GPS performance?

Comment: Basically? When it's not working. It's part of a troubleshooting process. In most circumstances, it's not needed. Of course, "not working" depends on the pilot's whims, and can include degraded performance. That part's a pretty gray area, to be honest.

Comment: that permission doesn't seem to work all the time?  Something about being a "system" app.  Any ideas?

Comment: @daveatflow It shouldn't have to be a system app to work. I'd suggest posting a separate, concise question, with code/manifest examples. The question you posted a few days ago wasn't very clear on the exact problem you are having. Make sure you include any error messages you receive.

Answer (score 4):

So far, the best answer to my question seems to be a combination of @Geobits' response and the XTRA injection code discussed in [Problems with sendExtraCommand and force_xtra_injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961514/problems-with-sendextracommand-and-force-xtra-injection). Based on this, I am currently using the following:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.sendExtraCommand(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,"delete_aiding_data", null);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
locationManager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_xtra_injection", bundle);
locationManager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_time_injection", bundle);
```

If anyone has additional ideas on how to improve this, or how to determine the best times to clear and download new GPS data, I would be very interested to hear.

Comment: did this make use of a network (data) connection?  Do we need to add permissions to our manifest to allow for that?

Comment: I think this permission is needed: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />