# in code, can one download the GPS almanac via wifi/3g and feed it to the GPS on an android phone

Tags: java, android, gps

Does anyone know if you can download the GPS almanac on an android phone.  Not through the GPS sat's but through wifi/3g.   And with said almanac then feed it to the GPS bits on my phone.

All in code.. (of course).. 
My phone takes some time to connect and a weak signal could be mitigated with the almanac.  Ironically with a weak signal it takes a long time to get the data from the sats.

Oh all on an unrooted phone in an app that is not system.

---

EDIT
@chopchop Pointed out that this is called assisted GPS, and it's not an easy thing.

stackoverflow.com/questions/14548707/ Requires extra permissions that seem to only be available to system apps, so that is no good for a "play" apk.

I shall continue to hunt (thanks all)

Comment: actually your phone always knows where it is... within between 50 and 300 meters, via the phone towers. I'm inside a building right now and it knows what suburb I'm in.  Not accurate enough to be of real use, but a good quick estimate, if it was all I had.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_signals#Almanac  Sorry mat, before you say I should learn about GPS.. how about google the terms I've used :)

Comment: -1 Doesn't look like you've actually done any of the homework yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: actually I had been to all the sites offered..  as none have worked, I'd hoped someone who'd done it would see the question..

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to download the almanacs from websites out there such as the official source here http://www.navcen.uscg.gov/?pageName=gpsAlmanacs. However I'm a 100% sure you won't be able to feed it to the GPS chip on your phone.

What you are trying to do is called Assisted-GPS and it's not that easy. Most devices out there already implement it and companies which do it have put a lot of effort and research into it. So not something you are going to be able to hack your way through any time in the future.

Check out the wikipedia page for some details on this technique:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS

Comment: Modern devices already use AGPS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_devices_with_Assisted_GPS

Comment: Edited the answer to give more info to the OP

Comment: I got a cheep (DEV) phone that often takes a long time to update the Assisted data, and every monday it's out of date.  I also have an app that I got off play that updates the assisted data (or seems to) and after that the phone is quick as.

Comment: OK have a look at this question for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548707/android-how-to-reset-and-download-a-gps-data

Comment: Yeah.. I already hit that wiki @chopchop. that's why I thought I could help out my little android.

Comment: the answer requires a change to the manifest, that seems to only work on system apps.  My older eclipse could compile it, but it never worked.  :)

Comment: Ok then why don't you edit this question to add the more specific items that you just mentionned